# Finding the Eigenspace corresponding to an eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations

For this problem, I was given the following matrix:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
  3 & 0 & 0 \\
  2 & 4 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 8
 \end{pmatrix}$$

One of the eigenvalues found, is $\lambda=8$. To find the eigenspace, I solved the following equations:

$$
(\lambda I-A)v=0 \implies 
\begin{pmatrix}
  5 & 0 & 0 \\
  -2 & -4 & 0 \\
  -1 & -1 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  a  \\
  b  \\
  c
 \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
  0  \\
  0  \\
  0
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

This leads to $5a=0 \implies a=0 \implies -2*0-4b=0 \implies b=0$. These equations do not give further information about $c$. My question here is, how to construct the eigenspace from this? At first I thought it would look like the following:

$$
E_8(A)=\left\{\left( \begin{smallmatrix}
  0  \\
  0  \\
  c
 \end{smallmatrix}\right): c\in\mathbb{R} \right\}= 
span\left( \begin{smallmatrix}
  0  \\
  0  \\
  1
 \end{smallmatrix}\right)
$$
Since $a=b=0$ and no matter what is picked for $c$, the equations still hold. However, by intuition and looking at $N(T)$, being the null-space of the linear transformation corresponding to the matrix $(\lambda I-A)$, I'm guessing that the eigenspace is two-dimensional.

I'm not sure how to go on from here as the only ''two-dimensional'' space I can think of by this, is a space consisting of $(0,0)$ which is not even two-dimensional.

Comment: the matrix is diagonalizable. it has 3 distinct eigenvalues and the dimension of its corresponding eigenspaces is 1-dimensional. $span(0,0,1)^T $ looks fine!

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix has 3 distinct eigenvalues ($3,4$, and $8)$, so it can be diagonalized and each eigenspace has dimension $1$.

By the way, your system is wrong, even if your final result is correct. The right linear system is $\begin{pmatrix}
  5 & 0 & 0 \\
  2 & -4 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  a  \\
  b  \\
  c\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0  \\ 0  \\
  0\end{pmatrix}$

You send get $a=0$, $b=0$ and $c$ arbitrary, which yields that your eigenspace is generated by $\begin{pmatrix}0  \\ 0  \\
  1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: You're right, the $-5$ was actually just a typo. However, when I found other spaces with eigenvalues $3,4$, I didn't immediately see that they were one-dimensional. They only had one variable, but it looked like $\{(0, -4c, c): c\in\mathbb{R}\}$ for eigenvalue $\lambda=4$. As the second entry is a multiple of the third entry, does that mean you can see it does not add a dimension, even if the entries are not the exact same?

Comment: I confess I don't understand your question. Since $(0,-4c,c)=c(0,-4,1)$ , your subspace is spanned by one non-zero vector $(0,-4,1)$, so has dimension $1$, since a basis of your eigenspace consists of a single vector. You should have a look back to the definition of dimension of a vector space, I think...