# Different way of writing vectors involving fractions in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

I solved the eigenvector of a matrix to be [4/5,1] the back of my book has it written as [4,5]. Are these the same answers just written differently?

Comment: If $v$ is an eigenvector of a matrix, then so is $cv$ for any nonzero scalar $c$. (Try to prove this yourself.) In this sense, eigenvectors are not unique, so a question asking for "the" eigenvector is not well-written.

Comment: take another look at the definitions of eigenvector, eigenvalue

Comment: Okay thank you for the answers. So in this case the only difference between the two would be a scalar (c) of 5? making them equivalent?

Comment: you might want to learn the "eigenspace" idea also, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2736625

Answer (score 1):

Any two eigenvectors which are scalar multiples of each other are equivalent. As such there is never only one eigenvector for some eigenvalue, but an infinite family of them.

The definition of an eigenvector, v, for a corresponding eigenvalue, $\lambda$, of a matrix $M$ is:

$$Mv = \lambda v$$

If you multiply the vector v by a constant k then the equality will still hold, so kv is another eigenvector.